# Textarea placeholder not taking properties

Tags: html, css, placeholder

My problem is textarea placeholder is not taking css properties

I have HTML :

```
<textarea id="information" class="career-form-textbox" name="message" placeholder="Add a cover letter or anything else you want to
share.">
</textarea>
```

I have CSS :

```
input,
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #848484;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0.2;
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

input,
textarea:-moz-placeholder,
color #848484 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0.2;
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

input,
textarea::-moz-placeholder,
color #848484 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0.2;
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

input,
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder,
color #848484 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0.2;
  font-family: Open Sans;
}
```

but its not working,  thank in advance,  sorry for bad formatting
Browser : Chrome

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: Yes. Its working https://jsfiddle.net/priyasingh/u0g69nzv/

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have some semantic faults in your posted css code. Try this one:

```css
input,
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color: #848484;
}
input,
textarea:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color: #848484;
   opacity:  1;
}
input,
textarea::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color: #848484;
   opacity:  1;
}
input,
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
   color: #848484;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="information" class="career-form-textbox" name="message"
placeholder="Add a cover letter or anything else you want to
share."></textarea>
```

Comment: The first rule is right. But the other 3 have the opening brace at the wrong place (behind color).

Comment: Thank you sir didn't noticed that one